# Google charts with tooltips and colors

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have seen one post which shows how to make color but it uses a method which is i didnt understand and its little dificult for me. im using this method in fiddle which is easy But it didnt work HTML inside tooltips .

```
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Statistics', 'Amount', { role: 'style' } , { role: 'tooltip' }],
    ['Categories', 5, '#D9534F' , "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Xylocopa_virginica_male_face.jpg'  width='40px' height = '40px'/>"],
    ['Posts', 4, '#337AB7' , 'my tooltip'],
    ['Comments', 8, '#5CB85C' ,'<div>fff</div>'],
    ['Users', 3, '#F0AD4E' , '<b>hhh</b>'],
  ]);

var options = {
  chart: {
    title: 'Analysis',
    tooltip: { isHtml: true},
    subtitle: '',
  },
/*  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'], // Another coloring method*/
  bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
};

var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

chart.draw(data, options);
 }
```

[**Js Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/vu5e2tfz/3/)

thanks , hope if someone have a question i can edit and add something before votingdown :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, need to understand difference between *Classic* and *Material* charts...

*Classic* = `google.visualization.BarChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

*Material* = `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages: ['bar']`

*Material* charts **do not support** column roles -- `{role: 'style'} , {role: 'tooltip'}`

---

next, there are two things needed for html tooltips on a *Classic* chart...

1) a property on the column must exist -- `{role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}`

2) and the chart option -- `tooltip: { isHtml: true}`

however, it should not be within the `chart` option, which is for *Material* charts only
(remove `chart: {}`)

```
var options = {
  title: 'Analysis',
  tooltip: { isHtml: true}
};
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Statistics', 'Amount', {role: 'style'} , {role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}],
    ['Categories', 5, '#D9534F' , "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Xylocopa_virginica_male_face.jpg'  width='40px' height = '40px'/>"],
    ['Posts', 4, '#337AB7' , 'my tooltip'],
    ['Comments', 8, '#5CB85C' ,'<div>fff</div>'],
    ['Users', 3, '#F0AD4E' , '<b>hhh</b>'],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Analysis',
    tooltip: { isHtml: true}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barchart"></div>
```

Comment: Its not just helped :) it helped x 2 +2 :) . thanks doctor charts .